# How to convert EXCEL to SQL (I have 143864 row and 100 column in excel) total 48,316 KB

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, eer-model

[image]

I convert excel to csv first, then import to phpmyadmin only import 100 rows, I changed config.inc buffer size but still did not changed the result. Could you please help me ???
My main idea to do this, compare two tables on mysql workbench, I have one table already sql, i need excel to convert sql then i can use "compare schemas" creating EER Model of existing database.

Answer (score 0):

Good you described the purpose of this approach. This way I can tell you in advance that it will not help to convert that Excel data to a MySQL table.

The model features (sync, compare etc.) all work on meta data only. They do not consider any table content. So instead you should do a textual comparison, by converting the table you have in the server to CSV.

Comparing such large documents is however a challenge. If you only have a few changes then using a diff tool (visual like Araxis Merge or `diff` on the command line) may help. For larger changesets a small utility app (may self written) might be necessary.